# Selective send on TChan?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

AFAIK TChan acts as a hub, every message sent is seen by others right ?!
i want a TChan that acts as a switch to send a message to specific thread, and also support broadcasting.
is there such thing ?

Comment: Can't you just use a broadcast TChan and discard the messages that are addressed to the other threads?

Comment: well i thought about it ,but it sounds inefficient to wake up 1000 threads and just one receives it

Comment: Then I guess you should use a `Map ThreadId TChan` and do your own broadcasting.

Comment: is there a thread safe map in haskell ?

Comment: Because Haskell data is immutable, most data structures are thread safe already.  To modify mutable data from multiple threads, putting it in a `TVar` is probably the easiest approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I re-read your question.  This answer doesn't quite address "selective send", though it clarifies what a `TChan` can do.

The "broadcast" approach described below will wake up all listeners (though on the bright side, it won't make 1000 copies of each item).  To avoid this, use the `Map` approach as @Mikhail suggested.  I did this in my [chat server example](https://github.com/joeyadams/haskell-chat-server-example/blob/master/Main.hs).

---

A `TChan` is a FIFO queue:

- `writeTChan` adds an item to the end.
- `readTChan` reads an item from the beginning.

For example, the following example forks 10 threads which fight over a single channel:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad

main = do
    chan <- newTChanIO

    forM_ [1..10] $ \i ->
        forkIO $
            forever $ do
                x <- atomically $ readTChan chan
                putStrLn $ "Thread " ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show x

    mapM_ (atomically . writeTChan chan) [1..1000]

    -- Wait for channel to empty out
    atomically $ do
        empty <- isEmptyTChan chan
        when (not empty) retry
```

Here, each item is read by exactly one thread.

In contrast, the following example "broadcasts" a stream of items to 10 threads, by making ten copies of the channel using [dupTChan](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TChan.html#v%3adupTChan):

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad

main = do
    master <- newTChanIO

    forM_ [1..10] $ \i -> do
        chan <- atomically $ dupTChan master
        forkIO $
            forever $ do
                x <- atomically $ readTChan chan
                putStrLn $ "Thread " ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show x

    mapM_ (atomically . writeTChan master) [1..100]

    -- Give threads time to complete
    threadDelay 1000000
```

Now each thread gets all of the items written to the channel.

A couple subtleties to note:

- Items written to a channel prior to `dupTChan` will not appear in the new channel.  If we called `dupTChan` from the child threads rather than the main thread, some `writeTChan`s could happen first, meaning the children might not see all the items.
- Since nobody is reading the `master` channel, items written to it will pile up and will likely not be garbage collected.  To avoid this caveat, use [newBroadcastTChan](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TChan.html#v%3anewBroadcastTChan) to create the `master` channel.

Comment: your approach looks like erlang message passing style, each client has a private TChan and a map for broadcating (ets table in erlang).
do you think erlang is better than haskell for chat server application ?

Comment: @user1748906: I haven't done any Erlang, but I gather it has a really good concurrency model.  If you plan to write a program that's primarily communication and concurrency, I recommend trying it in Erlang first.  Even if you decide to port your program to Haskell later on, you'll take the ideas you learned from Erlang with you.